# Video tearing 18.04 nvidia

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, video, tearing

I've installed proprietary drivers, and I have powerful card. Running totem or smplayer I see lines in video (tearing).

```
jk@jk:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GM204 [GeForce GTX 980]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 3840x2160@30.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 980/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.77
jk@jk:~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Jan 16 10:44:28 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980     Off  | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 26%   48C    P0    53W / 195W |   1364MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1595      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            39MiB |
|    0      1668      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          49MiB |
|    0      1853      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           425MiB |
|    0      1984      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         167MiB |
|    0      3336      G   /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx               595MiB |
|    0      3933      G   ...quest-channel-token=6698622263273112210    62MiB |
|    0      5586      G   /usr/bin/totem                                18MiB |
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYWer86A20s

I imagine tl;dr being: nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0:3840x2160_30 +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"

HDMI-0:3840x2160_30 is part to change, HDMI-0 from xrandr